# Установочный пакет на Qt

Tags: qt

Кто-нибудь может подсказать что-нибудь про то, как собрать установочные пакеты для windows на Qt? Источник какой-то, или поделиться опытом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял и вам нужен инсталятор то можно не парится и взять что то вроде  этого: http://ru.sminstall.com/. Или если очень хотите на Qt. То напишите еще одну програмулю, добавьте ей в ресурсы все необходимые файлы устанавливаемой программы. А в коде просто копируйте файлы из ресурсов в нужные директории. Если нужно - внесите изменения в реестр.

Comment: Я немного неправильно выразился. собрать установочный пакет для windows не на Qt, а из файлов проекта Qt.

Comment: Всё равно ответ Freest правильный :) В установочный пакет добавляете скомпилированный в режиме Release EXE-файл, и DLL'ки, которые он использует.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Walker'ом узнать зависимости, и тупо распаковывать их в ту же папку, что и exe